# javascript functions executing without being called

Tags: javascript, html, telerik

I have JavaScript function that is supposed to called OnClientClicking but is getting called on page load.

```
 function SaveClientClicking(sender, eventArgs)
    {
        var FirstName = $find("<% = FN.ClientID %>");
        var FNtext = FirstName._value;
        var LastName = $find("<% = LN.ClientID %>");
        var LNtext = LastName._value;
        var Email = $find("<% = email.ClientID %>");
        var Emailtext = Email._value;

        if (FNtext == "")
        {
            alert("First Name can't be blank");
            eventArgs.set_cancel(true);

        }

        else if (LNtext == "") {
            alert("Last Name can't be blank");
            eventArgs.set_cancel(true);
        }

        else if (Emailtext == "") {
            alert("Email address can't be blank");
            eventArgs.set_cancel(true);
        }
    }
```

And another JavaScript function that is supposed to be called OnClientItemSelected but also is getting called on page load.

```
function Selecting(sender, eventArgs)
    {
        var Country = $find("<% = Country.ClientID %>");
        var CountryDR = Country.get_selectedItem().get_text();
        var State = $find("<% = State.ClientID %>");
        if (CountryDR != "United States")
        {
            State == "Outside of US";  
        }
    }
```

I am pretty new to JavaScript so any suggestions would be of great help.

Comment: where you have your functions defined?

Comment: in the script @PlexisPlexis

Comment: please post the code where you are calling them, there may be an error in the syntax there

Answer (score 0):

Your brackets dont add up i think that might be the problem

Comment: oops when copying my code over I forgot to add the brackets to end the functions @Jamil

Answer (score 0):

You have the ending brackerts in both functions missed, please correct it and check.

Comment: They are added. I forgot to copy them when I copied my code over @Plexis